# Import newman (postman) in typescript project?

Tags: typescript, postman, postman-collection-runner

I want to use newman (https://www.npmjs.com/package/newman) in a typescript project to execute postmancollection, but when getting an error when I import (import { Newman } from 'newman';) the module

I tried instruction provided in https://community.getpostman.com/t/running-newman-in-typescript-node-project/7932 to import javascript module to typescript by running npm install @types/node --save

```js
import { Newman } from 'newman';

export class PostmanCollectionExecution {

  public static async onBoardLoan(_numberOfLoan: number): Promise<boolean> {
    // call newman.run to pass `options` object and wait for callback
    await Newman.run({
      collection: require('./sample-collection.json'),
      reporters: 'cli'
      }, function (err) {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
          return false;
        }
      });
    return true;
 }
}
```

Error:
 - Failed: Cannot read property 'run' of undefined
 - [ts] Module '"/Users/joe.tharayil/enerbank.multidisbursement.web/node_modules/@types/newman/index"' has no exported member 'Newman'."

Is it possible to use newman in typescrip? If so how do import the module and provide and example of usage

Answer (score 4):

Since, you are using typescript, you need to install @types/newman module.

- `npm install @types/newman --save.`

And then, import newman like this `import * as newman from 'newman';`